# Is there a way to pass a generic Array as parameter

Tags: java

My question is quite simple:

I have the following method in my generic class (with type parameters A and B)

```
public void add(A elem, int pos, B[] assoc)
```

What I want to do is create a method

```
public void add(A elem, int pos)
```

which calls the upper method with a empty Array in assoc.
So far I havnt found a solution, since Java doesnt allows to instantiate arrays of generic types.

Comment: Here, `A` and `B` are generic type variables?

Comment: Are those generic methods? If so, you need to declare the type parameters.

Comment: Your question is not clear to us, at least to me :(

Comment: cant you just create empty array by `new Object[0]` and cast it (going to try now)

Comment: That's what Lists are for

Comment: A and B are type parameters of the generic class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to: generic array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation)

Answer (score 18):

Java generic method which accepts a generic array.

```
public <T> void printArray(T[] array){
        for (T element: array){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
```

The method which accepts generic list.

```
public <T> void printList(List<T> list){
      for (T element : list){
           System.out.println(element);
      }
}
```

Comment: Does this work? I get this error The method printArray(T[]) in the type MyClass is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

Comment: @AdamMendoza Template accepts only Object Type values, and you are trying to pass primitive data type (int), hence the error.

Comment: However this works for both int and char  public static <T> void test(T result, T expect) {...}. It doesn't allow arrays of primitives but primitives by themselves are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, Java doesn't support generic arrays creation, but thats probably because of [how generic works](http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html), in short, generics matter only at compile time, after compilation all generic classes are just Object classes, so thats why you cant create generic array.

However, you can create an empty `Object` array and cast it:

```
class Generic<B> {
    public void add(A a, int pos, B[] assoc) {
        System.out.println("Length: " + assoc.length);
    }

    public void add(A a, int pos) {
        add(a, pos, (B[]) new Object[0]);
    }
}
```

when i call `add` without that array it prints 0 as expected.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: There should be no problem with such an assignment. The danger is when retrieving items from the array (where an implicit cast is added, so you may get ClassCastException), and when storing items in the array (where you may get ArrayStoreException). None of these can occur in this case. Remember that B[] is an array of type Object[] at runtime.

Comment: @Eyal You are correct. I was testing something unrelated that I thought was related and misjudging the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For two generic class `AClass<T>` and `BClass<T>` i can think of one way: Taking the advantage of `varargs` and using two different named function `add()` and `addA()`:

```
public static <T>void addA(AClass<T> elem, int pos, BClass<T>... assoc){}

public static <T>void add(AClass<T> elem, int pos)
{
   addA(elem, pos);
}
```

Comment: well, varargs can be tricky and i would avoid it if possible. Consider following scenario: function `foo(Object... o) { ... }` is called with 1 argument which happens to be array of objects (like `foo(new Object[]{"asd", 45, '6', false}`) now what happens? Suprisingly, the array unwraps and `foo` recives 4 arguments!

Comment: yes it can be tricky for the scenario you have given. But i don't think there is any other way with `generic class` keeping the type intact without varargs.